# How to securely connect to Heroku Redis via the command line?

Tags: security, heroku, redis, stunnel

The [Heroku Redis CLI documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/securing-heroku-redis#heroku-redis-cli) states that connecting via the Heroku CLI is insecure, as it relies on the `redis-cli` binary.

Is there a secure way to connect to a Heroku Redis instance via a command-line interface? Connecting via my local machine, or though a dyno as a relay both work fine.

Comment: down vote
I'm wondering about this as well. After installing the Stunnel buildpack, I didn't receive the insecure action warning anymore, but I'm not sure what this actually means.

It's also not immediately clear how I verify that Stunnel is actually working as I don't have stunnel locally and thus have a flag in my procfile to invoke the stunnel binary based on an environment variable. Edit: Answered rather than commented, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you're using the `hobby-dev` tier of Heroku Redis which seems not to support SSL.

> SSL for Heroku Redis is only available on production tier plans. The hobby-dev plan is meant for testing and staging environments, not production.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/securing-heroku-redis

Similar Q answered here: [How can I securely connect to Heroku-hosted Redis from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247368/how-can-i-securely-connect-to-heroku-hosted-redis-from-the-command-line)