# How can I securely connect to Heroku-hosted Redis from the command line?

Tags: security, heroku, redis

There's an older question about this, but no answers: [How to securely connect to Heroku Redis via the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302212/how-to-securely-connect-to-heroku-redis-via-the-command-line)

How are people connecting to Redis remotely? Just ignoring the security warning when running `heroku redis:cli`?

> WARNING: Insecure action. All data, including the Redis password, will
>   not be encrypted.

Or is it simply "Don't do that"? The article linked from the older post mentions that redis-cli connections are insecure, but only discusses how to subvert the warning.

I was surprised not to find more discussion about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because you're using the `hobby-dev` tier of Heroku Redis which seems not to support SSL. According to Heroku here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/securing-heroku-redis

> SSL for Heroku Redis is only available on production tier plans. The hobby-dev plan is meant for testing and staging environments, not production.

If you upgrade a premium or higher plan you shouldn't have this issue.